# insert value into same id

Tags: php, mysql

I created a quiz and I have problem with answers. When I input the answer, the answer want to insert in to id that is play the game. Instead it creates another id in the table. How can I input multiple answers in different columns but same row?

I tried like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
    $box = $_POST['opt'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO gamer (jedan) VALUES ('$box')";
    if(mysqli_query($connsql, $sql)) {
        header('Location:qu2.php');  
    } else {  
        echo'Odgovor nije ubacen!';
   }  
}
```

Comment: Do you set the field ID to auto_increment in DB?

Comment: You can't *insert* into an existing row, you can *update* it. Please show your database structure and show what rows you have, what you want to change in them and what exact error you're getting.

Comment: id
int(11)
NO
PRI
NULL
auto_increment
username
varchar(128)
NO
NULL
jedan
varchar(128)
NO
NULL
dva
varchar(128)
NO
NULL
tri
varchar(128)
NO
NULL
cetiri
varchar(128)
NO
NULL

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: yes i know, this is just a test.. tnx for replay

Answer (score 0):

You want to use *update*, not *insert*.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE gamer
    SET jedan = ?
    WHERE id = ?;
```

Note that you should be using *parameterized* queries rather than munging query strings.  This is especially important in your case, because the answer to a question could contain all sorts of characters that would break the SQL query.

Comment: i was tried with update but i can't select the last id